Map single property from class to every object in list of other class
Using MapStruct, I would like to map my RecipientDTO to Recipient. I want the AddressDTO from RecipientDTO to become the Address in every Subscription of Recipient.subscriptions. How do I achieve this with MapStruct? My classes look like this:
public class AddressDTO {
    String street;
    String city;
}

public class SubscriptionDTO {
    String category;
}

public class RecipientDTO {
    String name;
    AddressDTO address;
    List<SubscriptionDTO> subscriptions;
}

public class Address {
    String street;
    String city;
}

public class Subscription {
    Address address;
    String category;
}

public class Recipient {
    String name;
    List<Subscription> subscriptions;
}

I have tried specifying a separate mapper interface for Subscription. So
@Mapper
public interface SubscriptionMapper {
  SubscriptionMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SubscriptionMapper.class);

  @Mapping(target = "address", source = "addressDTO")
  Subscription toSubscription(SubscriptionDTO dto, AddressDTO addressDTO);
}

This will generate a mapper for subscription.
But when I do
@Mapper(uses = SubscriptionMapper.class)
public interface RecipientMapper {
  RecipientMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(RecipientMapper.class);


  Recipient toRecipient(RecipientDTO recipientDTO);
}

it will not use the mapping method with extra parameter from SubscriptionMapper.
I would like to do something like this if possible:
@Mapping(target = "subscriptions.address", source = "address")
Recipient toRecipient(RecipientDTO recipientDTO);


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You need to use @AfterMapping annotation. This annotation allows you to add custom code after the standard mapping process.
@Mapper
public interface RecipientMapper {
    RecipientMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(RecipientMapper.class);

    Recipient toRecipient(RecipientDTO recipientDTO);

    @AfterMapping
    default void updateAddresses(RecipientDTO recipientDTO, @MappingTarget Recipient recipient) {
        if(Objects.nonNull(recipient) && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(recipient.getSubscriptions())){
            recipient.getSubscriptions().forEach(rcpt -> {
                var address = recipientDTO.getAddress();
                rcpt.setAddress(Address.builder().city(address.getCity()).street(address.getStreet()).build());
            });
        }
    }
}


Thank you this works. Would there be another option which doesn't involve me having to add a setter on subscription for the address? At the moment I was using builders only for creating the instance of the object.

I don't think so. The instance is already created for this, you need to use the setter to update a specific field value. Don't forget to upvote the answer please.

I'd add method Address toAddress(AddressDTO addressDTO), then call that instead of manually building: rcpt.setAddress(toAddress(address)). If you want to keep the new method out of the public API of the mapper you can turn the mapper into an abstract class and make the new method protected abstract.
